# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need help in solving this.

The **"read"** method on the **doc** object shows this error:
**ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.**

Please, how do it solve this

```
def send_comment_mail_notification(request, space, target_email):
    message = request.POST.get('description', '')
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
    from_mail = space.email
    to = target_email
    msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, from_mail, [to],)
    doc = request.FILES['document']
    print(doc.read())
    msg.attach(doc.name, doc.read(), doc.content_type)
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()
```

```
class CommentViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    permission_classes = (BelongToSpace, )
    serializer_class = serializers.CommentSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, FileUploadParser)
    queryset = models.Comment.objects.all()

    def callback(self, **kwargs):
        return send_comment_mail_notification(self.request, self.space, "aa@gmail.com")
```

Here is the traceback
[image]

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: This will not work since the serializer will handle the file first, and thus by the time you send the notification, the file is already "consumed".

Comment: Try saving the data you want in variables. `name =  doc.name`, `contenttype =doc content_type`, `content = doc.read()` before printing  then pass the vars in the msg.attach

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, I already added the traceback

Comment: @BendikKnapstad, I tried it, it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it, I don't know if this is the best solution. Thanks to @Willem comment

I excluded the "document" field in the serializers.py file under the CommentSerilaizer, then it was possible to call the "read" method on the "doc" object.

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
comment_cat_detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
creator_detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = models.Comment
    # fields = "__all__"
    exclude = ('document', )
```